# How to convert tensorflow .pb file to .bytes?

Tags: unity-game-engine, tensorflow

I am trying to convert the android tensorflow example provided in the tensorflow github into a Unity project. I have a .pb file for ssd_mobilenet_v1_android_export. But to use tensorflow models in Unity you have to have the model in a .bytes format. I can't figure out how to convert my .pb file to .bytes. I was going to use this code but I don't have any checkpoints for this graph, only the .pb file.

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph = model_path +'/raw_graph_def.pb',
              input_binary = True,
              input_checkpoint = last_checkpoint,
              output_node_names = "action",
              output_graph = model_path +'/your_name_graph.bytes' ,
              clear_devices = True, initializer_nodes = "",input_saver = "",
              restore_op_name = "save/restore_all", filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0")
```

Is there a simple way to do this conversion? Or a simple way to get a checkpoint for this model? It seems like this should be obvious but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just switch extension from `.pb` to `.bytes` and for most cases this will work just fine. Check my [TF Classify example](https://github.com/Syn-McJ/TFClassify-Unity) for Unity.